# How to bypass Firebase authentication when app is offline?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have the following scenario: a Flutter application backed by a Spring Boot application on AWS. The first time a user tries to log in, they are authenticated by Spring Security with OAuth2 and get a JWT token which is kept in the app's memory for future interactions.

In addition to this first token, there is a secondary Firebase token, signed with a Firebase private key, which is used for all interactions with the Firestore database.

The Firebase connection is well handled, including during loss of Internet connectivity, but whenever a user tries to (first- or re)open the app and Internet connection is unavailable, it hangs during the Firebase sign in.

Is there any way to bypass this?
I know they can't authenticate without an Internet connection, but I would like to allow users to access their Firestore local cache while they are offline.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable offline persistence, in web it is disabled by default:

```dart
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
  .catch(function(err) {
      if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
          // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
          // in one tab at a a time.
          // ...
      } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
          // The current browser does not support all of the
          // features required to enable persistence
          // ...
      }
  });
```

You can learn more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)

Comment: I realized that offline persistence is enabled by default on Android. I couldn't figure out any way to bypass authentication when offline in the link you shared, @Code Eagle

Comment: I think authentication always needs an active connection, anyway your app will still work while offline till restore internet activity and then get the refresh token again, i think all what you can do is to extend the expiration date of refresh token @Jaumzera,